# Pandas: 'read_csv' function from AWS S3 bucket sometimes returns "FileNotFoundError"

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I developed an AWS lambda which is triggered on an s3 event (file creation) in 'eu-west-1' region.
This lambda reads the "csv" file that triggered it and then processes it (it therefore exists!)... total execution time is 4 secondes max.
Files arrive every 10 seconds or so, and it has always worked perfectly for several weeks.
Today, for 20 minutes, the "FileNotFoundError" exception systematically caused an error when the lambda reading the file that triggered it.
A few minutes later, when I manually re-upload the files that generated an error, the lambda runs successfully.

Here is a sample of the lambda code:

```
import pandas as pd
import boto3

...

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    for record in event['Records']:
        bucket_name = record['s3']['bucket']['name']
        source_key = unquote_plus(record['s3']['object']['key'])

        df = pd.read_csv(f"s3://{bucket_name}/{source_key}", sep=',', index_col=0)  # Returns sometimes "FileNotFoundError"
...
```

Here are the error logs returned for a lambda execution:

```
[ERROR] FileNotFoundError: frefin-bitbot-prd-202714940105-eu-west-1-data/data/collection/kraken/order_book/depth-100/compilation/xxbtzusd/timeframe-10/shift-0/XXBTZUSD_1599718540_1599718550_10_0.csv
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/entrypoint.py", line 96, in lambda_handler
    df = pd.read_csv(f"s3://{bucket_name}/{source_key}", sep=',', index_col=0)
  File "/var/task/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 686, in read_csv
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "/var/task/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 435, in _read
    filepath_or_buffer, encoding, compression
  File "/var/task/pandas/io/common.py", line 222, in get_filepath_or_buffer
    filepath_or_buffer, mode=mode or "rb", **(storage_options or 
{}
)
  File "/var/task/fsspec/core.py", line 133, in open
    out = self.__enter__()
  File "/var/task/fsspec/core.py", line 101, in __enter__
    f = self.fs.open(self.path, mode=mode)
  File "/var/task/fsspec/spec.py", line 844, in open
    **kwargs
  File "/var/task/s3fs/core.py", line 378, in _open
    autocommit=autocommit, requester_pays=requester_pays)
  File "/var/task/s3fs/core.py", line 1097, in __init__
    cache_type=cache_type)
  File "/var/task/fsspec/spec.py", line 1134, in __init__
    self.details = fs.info(path)
  File "/var/task/s3fs/core.py", line 527, in info
    if self.version_aware or (key and self._ls_from_cache(path) is None) or refresh:
  File "/var/task/fsspec/spec.py", line 321, in _ls_from_cache
    raise FileNotFoundError(path)
```

I have two questions about that:

1. Do you have an explanation for this error?
2. How to best manage this situation?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to best manage this situation?

I don't have explanation for why it happened, but I have some ideas how to deal with it, or at least try to manage such situations. You can implement [error retries and exponential backoff](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/api-retries.html) in your function. If an error occurs, you catch it, and retry few times with different delays.

If the backoff does not help, and the failure is is quaranteed, you can setup [dead letter queue](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/invocation-async.html#dlq) for your function to capture "bad" S3 events that lead to these errors. This way you can can automatically respond to them, e.g. get notification and troubleshoot.

Comment: Thanks for your help. The error was systematic, but for a period of a few minutes (it has not happened again until today), I think the dead letter queue feature is a good solution associated with implement error retries and exponential backoff